# Cross-compiling R for ARM (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: c, r, arm, fortran, raspberry-pi

I need to build R (http://www.r-project.org/) for Arch Linux ARM running on Raspberry Pi.  I am having trouble running ./configure.  I have built my own toolchain using crosstool-ng and it does work, I've compiled other applications with it just fine.

The issue appears to be that I cannot link the Fortran libraries to C code.  Here is where configure fails:

```
checking for Fortran 77 libraries of gfortran...  -L/home/njackson/bcm2708rpi-toolchain/lib -L/home/njackson/bcm2708rpi-toolchain/lib/gcc/arm-rpi-linux-gnueabi/4.7.3 -L/home/njackson/bcm2708rpi-toolchain/arm-rpi-linux-gnueabi/lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../.. -lgfortran -lm /home/njackson/bcm2708rpi-toolchain/arm-rpi-linux-gnueabi/lib/libgfortran.a /home/njackson/bcm2708rpi-toolchain/lib/gcc/arm-rpi-linux-gnueabi/4.7.3/libgcc.a
checking for dummy main to link with Fortran 77 libraries... unknown
configure: error: in `/home/njackson/R-2.15.3':
configure: error: linking to Fortran libraries from C fails
See `config.log' for more details
```

It fails here.

I used the following configure command:

```
./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf CC=/home/njackson/bcm2708rpi-toolchain/bin/arm-rpi-linux-gnueabi-gcc CXX=/home/njackson/bcm2708rpi-toolchain/bin/arm-rpi-linux-gnueabi-g++ FC=/home/njackson/bcm2708rpi-toolchain/bin/arm-rpi-linux-gnueabi-gfortran MAIN_LD=/home/njackson/bcm2708rpi-toolchain/bin/arm-rpi-linux-gnueabi-ld --with-readline=no
```

I'd appreciate help getting this compiled.  Thanks.

Comment: does `config.log` have anything useful to say?

Comment: Not really, I couldn't find anything useful other than what was already in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

One should set F77=/path/to/gfortran instead of the FC variable.

Comment: How about the rest of the environment variables, and any particulars to the toolchain?

Comment: I don't know yet.  The Fortran compiler does work.  I'm actually still having a problem with linking.